# Using bitronox manager, XA not working with my custom dev-kit adapter

Tags: mule, mule-esb, bitronix

I developed my custom connector with dev-kit, my connector act as a source it connect to ejb and extract the data, and send to the another end point.

I am using bitronix for transaction manager.

I used the below code to register my ejb in the mule transaction context.

```
public static void registerXaResource(MuleContext muleContext) {
    EJBClientTransactionContext txContext = EJBClientTransactionContext.create(muleContext.getTransactionManager(),
            getSynchronizationRegistry());
    EJBClientTransactionContext.setGlobalContext(txContext);
    XaResourceProducer.registerXAResource("dummyResource", new DummyXaResource());
}

/**
 * @return
 */
private static TransactionSynchronizationRegistry getSynchronizationRegistry() {
    return TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionSynchronizationRegistry();
}
```

After that am using next end point as JMS and configured with XA,always join.
But it not behave as XA.
It looks like bitronix delisting the JMS resource.

```
2019-12-11 16:59:48,398 [Receiving Thread] DEBUG 

bitronix.tm.resource.jms.DualSessionWrapper - choosing XA session
2019-12-11 16:59:48,410 [Receiving Thread] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.jms.DualSessionWrapper - looking for producer based on a MessageProducerConsumerKey on ActiveMQQueue[sampleReplyQueue]
2019-12-11 16:59:48,410 [Receiving Thread] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.jms.DualSessionWrapper - found no producer based on a MessageProducerConsumerKey on ActiveMQQueue[sampleReplyQueue], creating it
2019-12-11 16:59:48,411 [Receiving Thread] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.jms.DualSessionWrapper - choosing XA session
2019-12-11 16:59:48,447 [Receiving Thread] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.jms.DualSessionWrapper - closing a DualSessionWrapper in state ACCESSIBLE of a JmsPooledConnection of pool 1605822565-inboundtest-JMS in state ACCESSIBLE with underlying connection org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQXAConnection@207dd1b7
2019-12-11 16:59:48,447 [Receiving Thread] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.TransactionContextHelper - delisting a DualSessionWrapper in state ACCESSIBLE of a JmsPooledConnection of pool 1605822565-inboundtest-JMS in state ACCESSIBLE with underlying connection org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQXAConnection@207dd1b7 from a Bitronix Transaction with GTRID [31363035383232353635000000002582E13C00000001], status=ACTIVE, 1 resource(s) enlisted (started Thu Jan 08 12:18:54 IST 1970)
2019-12-11 16:59:48,447 [Receiving Thread] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.TransactionContextHelper - resource is not in enlisting global transaction context: a DualSessionWrapper in state ACCESSIBLE of a JmsPooledConnection of pool 1605822565-inboundtest-JMS in state ACCESSIBLE with underlying connection org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQXAConnection@207dd1b7
2019-12-11 16:59:48,447 [Receiving Thread] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.TransactionContextHelper - requeuing a DualSessionWrapper in state ACCESSIBLE of a JmsPooledConnection of pool 1605822565-inboundtest-JMS in state ACCESSIBLE with underlying connection org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQXAConnection@207dd1b7 from a Bitronix Transaction with GTRID [31363035383232353635000000002582E13C00000001], status=ACTIVE, 1 resource(s) enlisted (started Thu Jan 08 12:18:54 IST 1970)
2019-12-11 16:59:48,447 [Receiving Thread] DEBUG bitronix.tm.resource.common.TransactionContextHelper - resource is not in enlisting global transaction context: a DualSessionWrapper in state ACCESSIBLE of a JmsPooledConnection of pool 1605822565-inboundtest-JMS in state ACCESSIBLE with underlying connection org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQXAConnection@207dd1b7
```

As per the logs the JMS not comes under the transaction which i begin.

Or else right way to implement XA Mule custom connector.

Comment: You should post your complete question here, instead of referencing a question elsewhere.

Comment: @aled done, try to implement XA by using bitronix in mule custom connector

Comment: I got this reply from bitronix team https://github.com/bitronix/btm/issues/108#event-2880704388

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Devkit doesn't support transactions. Probably just registering the resource in that way is not enough to fully implement the XA transaction.

The SDK for Mule 4 does support [transactions](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/transactions) though I understand this is not the version you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes we are using dev-kit, give some sample to implement in Mule 4 SDK. @aled

Comment: I'm sorry don't have an example of a connector with transactions for Mule SDK. You can follow Mule SDK docs to create one: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/
Note that Mule SDK is for Mule 4 only, and DevKit is for Mule 3 only, and they are incompatible, however there is a how to migrate from DevKit to Mule SDK page in the docs: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/dmt

Comment: i tried with AMQ and JMS queue its working as XA fine. How? the flow screen shot is attached.

Comment: In Mule 3 JMS is not a connector created with DevKit. They are transports, implemented internally in the runtime by the Mule developers.

Comment: ok Thanks @aled, but i tired by add below lines. Its working fine.      ExternalXaTransactionextenaXATransaction = new ExternalXaTransaction(super.muleContext);
                 TransactionCoordination.getInstance().bindTransaction(extenaXATransaction);

Comment: It might work, I'm just pointing out that DevKit doesn't provide any support for it.

Comment: yes your are rite. Thanks for your quick response for all my queries.